# WP7 silverlight toolkit problem with TransitionFrame.Completed

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7, toolkit

I have problem with TransitionFrame.Completed event in new release of Silverlight Toolkit.
In ealier version I can make event on:

```
TransitionFrame.Completed += TransitionFrame_Completed
```

In new version looks like that staff was changed.

Any solution for that?
Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: Which version are you refering to as the "new release"? It was last updated in February.

Comment: Yes, I mean Feb 2011, ealier release don't have Performance ProgressBar included -> http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/progressbarperftips2/

Comment: That was very usefull event becouse, now I have to load my data in Loaded page event but in the same time animation sometimes can drop smoothness. With TransitionFrame.Completed I didn't have that problem.

Comment: what is your actual question? What stuff was changed? what used to work? and what is now different?

Comment: My question does not change. Why in actual version I can't find Completed event in TransitionFrame which was in ealier version when I used it? Soo ok some changes was made but how can I now implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talk with Silverlight toolkit development team and there is no event such as TransitionFrame.Complited.
My mistake, becouse I found on net some Silverlight toolkit reworked by ComponentArt company.

But developer from Silverlight toolkit agree with that this event could by default in library.

For now I am using Telerik library were you can find that event.
It is very useful becouse you can start making some things when you are certain that page transition is completed.